# Google Sheets - download csv to computer, in a certain folder.

Tags: bash, google-docs-api

Does anybody have any ideas on a possible script to do this, that would download and automatically overwrite the previous download?

Comment: I would look at `wget`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to download a file to a specific location:

```
wget http://locationforfilebeinghosted.com/file -P /Some/Location
```

With wget, there is not a way to overwrite files. You could use `-N` which will check timestamps, but this will not overwrite when you download unless the actual timestamps of the file hosted on the website are newer.

So you could:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 wget http://locationforfilebeinghosted.com/file -P ${someLocation}
 mv -f ${someLocation} ${newLocation]
```

which should overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget like already mentioned or curl

```
$(curl -s http://linktofile) > filename
```

The -s is the silent option.